# What is the relationship between Rank of square matrix and its higher orders?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix, and $\operatorname{Rank}(A^{2})=3$, then can we establish any relationship to determine the rank of $A$? If it helps, $A$ has three distinct eigenvalues and it is a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Also, I want to know if there is a theorem or general statement about figuring out ranks of matrices of higher orders than the original one.

Comment: Can $A^2$ have larger rank than $A$? Conversely, if $A$ has full rank, then what is the rank of $A^2$?

Comment: So, $A$ should also have rank 3?

Comment: @rust32627 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^2$ has Eigenvalue $0$ and an Eigenspace of $0$ of dimension $1$. This means $A$ has also Eigenvalue $0$

(there are several ways to see that for example $\det(A^2)=0=\det(A)\det(A)$)

This means $\text{rank(A)}<4$. Now we need to verify that $\text{rank}(A^2)\le \text{rank}(A)$

Its sufficient to show $\ker(A)\subseteq \ker(A^2)$:

Let $v\in \ker(A) \Longleftrightarrow Av=0 \Longrightarrow A^2v=A(Av)=A0=0\Longrightarrow v\in\ker(A^2)$

$\ker(A)\subseteq \ker(A^2)$

concluding $\text{rank}(A)=3$

---

In general its not that easy, consider a nilpotent endomorphism.

$\text{rank}(A)\ge\text{rank}(A^2)\ge\text{rank}(A^3)...$

and you usually cannot say anything about the ranks without doing some calculations

A information which can help alot is knowing the algebraic and geometric multiplicity. It can help you to understand the structure and get informations about the ranks.

---

*For your question in the comment:*

Okey first of all, the case that the rank of $A^n$ is full, which means, $A^n$ is invertable, gives you (take for example the determinant argument I stated above) that the rank of $A$ is also full. So in general only endomorphisms with no full rank are interesting. And btw if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$, so is $\lambda^{1/n}$ for $A$.

So $A^n$ has an eigenvalue $0$ (the other case is already clear from above). There are two cases which are important to understand:

Is the geometric multiplicity $\ne$ algebraic multiplicity for eigenvalue $0$ of $A$, then and only then $\text{rank}(A)\ne\text{rank}(A^n)$, $n>1$. It helps to look over the theory of the *jordan canonical form*.

Comment: If I exclude nilpotent matrix, then can it be generalized?  
And thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I answered in my post :)